# Angular - How to validate two pairs of fields independently

Tags: angular

I want to validate two pairs of fields independently.

One pair of fields is the password. I want to check that they are the same.

The second pair of fields is the email address. I want to check that they are the same.

The method below doesn't work or I just don't know how to do it.

I can not. Tell me how to do it?

```
        export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

          loginForm!:FormGroup;


          constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
          }

          ngOnInit(): void {

            this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({

              email1: ['', {
                validators: [Validators.required]
              }],

              email2: ['', {
                validators: [Validators.required]
              }],

              password1: ['', {
                validators: [Validators.required]
              }],

              password2: ['', {
                validators: [Validators.required]
              }]

            },

            {validators: this.matchData('email1','email2', 'password1', 'password2')});

          }

          get email1() {
            return this.loginForm.controls['email1'];
          }

          get email2() {
            return this.loginForm.controls['email2'];
          }

          get password1() {
            return this.loginForm.controls['password1'];
          }

          get password2() {
            return this.loginForm.controls['password2'];
          }


          public matchData(email1: any, email2: any, password1: any, password2: any): ValidatorFn {

            return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

              let passwordOne = control.get(password1)?.value;
              let passwordTwo = control.get(password2)?.value;

              let emailOne = control.get(email1)?.value;
              let emailTwo = control.get(email2)?.value;

              if (passwordOne != passwordTwo) {
                return { 'noMatchPass': true }
              }
                return null

            }
          }


        }
```

HTML

```
    <input type="email" formControlName="email1">
    <div *ngIf="email1.errors?.['required']"> Email address required </div>

    <input type="email" formControlName="email2">
    <div *ngIf="email2.errors?.['required']"> Email address required </div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('noMatchEmail')">Email address does not match</div>


    <input type="password" formControlName="password1">
    <div *ngIf="password1.errors?.['required']"> Password required </div>

    <input type="password" formControlName="password2">
    <div *ngIf="password2.errors?.['required']"> Password required </div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('noMatchPass')"> Passwords do not match </div>
```

Comment: You can just create a validator to check if two string are equals, and use it twice, once for the emails, and once for the password. Instead of checking everything at once.

Comment: Please show with an example. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939157/angular-conditional-required-validator-between-two-fields/65939591#65939591

Comment: This is not the right decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <br><br><br>

  <form [formGroup]="loginForm">


    <label for="email1">Email</label>
    <br>
    <input type="email" (ngModelChange)="changeFieldMail()" formControlName="email1" id="email1">
    <div *ngIf="email1.errors?.['required']"> Necessarily </div>

    <br><br>

    <label for="email2">Repeat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="email" (ngModelChange)="changeFieldMail()" formControlName="email2" id="email2">
    <div *ngIf="email2.errors?.['required']"> Necessarily </div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('noMatchMail')">Email address does not match</div>

    <br><br><br><br>

    <label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" (ngModelChange)="changeFieldPass()" formControlName="password1" id="password1">
    <div *ngIf="password1.errors?.['required']"> Necessarily </div>

    <br><br>

    <label for="password2">Repeat</label>
    <input type="password" (ngModelChange)="changeFieldPass()" formControlName="password2" id="password2">
    <div *ngIf="password2.errors?.['required']"> Necessarily </div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('noMatchPass')">Passwords do not match</div>

    <br><br>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" >
      Отправить
    </button>



  </form>
```

HTML

```
  import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
  import {Router} from "@angular/router";

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styles: [``],
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {




    loginForm:FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({email1: [''], email2: [''], password1: [''], password2: ['']});


    public editMail!:boolean;
    public editPass!:boolean;



    constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                 private router: Router,) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          email1: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ],
            updateOn: 'change'
          }],
          email2: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ],
            updateOn: 'change'
          }],
          password1: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ],
            updateOn: 'change'
            /* change
               blur
               submit */
          }],
          password2: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
            ],
            updateOn: 'change'
            /* change
               blur
               submit */
          }]
        }, {validators: this.matchPassword('email1', 'email2', 'password1', 'password2')});



    }

    get email1() {
      return this.loginForm.controls['email1'];
    }

    get email2() {
      return this.loginForm.controls['email1'];
    }

    get password1() {
      return this.loginForm.controls['password1'];
    }

    get password2() {
      return this.loginForm.controls['password2'];
    }

    // Сверяем два пароля на одинаковость
    public matchPassword(email1: any, email2: any, password1: any, password2: any): ValidatorFn {

      return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {


        if (this.editMail) {
          let mailOne = control.get(email1)?.value;
          let mailTwo = control.get(email2)?.value;

          if (mailOne != mailTwo) {
            return { 'noMatchMail': true }
          }
        } else if (this.editPass) {
          let passwordOne = control.get(password1)?.value;
          let passwordTwo = control.get(password2)?.value;

          if (passwordOne != passwordTwo) {
            return { 'noMatchPass': true }
          }
        }



        return null;

      }
    }



    changeFieldMail() {
      this.editMail = true
      this.editPass = false
    }


    changeFieldPass() {
      this.editMail = false
      this.editPass = true
    }

  }
```

https://github.com/Favorskij/matchAng

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-asdfva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validator, for an example this code below is a custom validator for `match.validator.ts`:

```
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormGroup,
  ValidationErrors,
  ValidatorFn,
} from "@angular/forms";
export const matchValidator = (
  matchWith: string,
  message?: string
): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const value = control.value;
    if (value) {
      const formGroup = control.parent as FormGroup;
      const defaultError = {
        value,
        expectedValue: "",
      };
      if (formGroup && formGroup.get(matchWith) instanceof AbstractControl) {
        const matchValue = formGroup.get(matchWith)?.value;
        if (value !== matchValue) {
          defaultError.expectedValue = matchValue;
          return {
            ...defaultError,
            message: message,
          };
        }
        formGroup.get(matchWith)?.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
          control.updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      } else {
        if (control.value !== matchWith) {
          defaultError.expectedValue = matchWith;
          return {
            ...defaultError,
            message: message,
          };
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
};
```

Now you can use that's match validator like an angular validator.

For an example:

```js
this.formGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
  email: [null],
  confirmEmail: [
    null,
    Validators.compose([
      matchValidator('email', 'Confirm email does not match with email'),
    ]),
  ],
  password: [null],
  confirmPassword: [
    null,
    Validators.compose([
      matchValidator(
        'password',
        'Confirm password does not match with password'
      ),
    ]),
  ],
});
```

Live Code:: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rltfm5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Live Preview:: https://angular-ivy-rltfm5.stackblitz.io

I hope it can help.

Comment: You're subscribing to valueChanges several, several, several times. The validator function is executed several times along live of application (when you change the FormControl and some times more)

Comment: I think it will only execute when value change from that control. Imagine some a component has been destroyed, it's mean that's valueChanges is never called because there's not value changes for that's control.

Comment: try adding a `console.log("hi")` inside subscribe function -really I don't check it, sorry-

Comment: It works, but it's a little wry.

Comment: @MarieSpeak oh ok, I hope someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: @Titus Sutio Fanpula In any case, thank you very much. I took your example into account.

Comment: @Titus Sutio Fanpula I did it differently and it works great. See post below.

Comment: @MarieSpeak's of course, everything is can, but the problem is when you want to use it in another place, you have to do it multiple times ("redefine")  and the different between mys and your's is when I want to use multiple validator, I dont heve to define an error multiple times in my html code, because I just need to use `message` to show error for all control. And it will make my code little bit simple and when I want to change someting, then everything will be change, without I cange it manualy one by one.