# angular 14 reactive forms validators don't work with custom validators

Tags: angular

I'm using Reactive Forms in Angular 14. I made a custom validator to check time and I also want the Validators.required validator to be added. but what I get is that custom validator is working fine but required isn't working at all.

my formGroup in TS file

```
 this.form = this.builder.group(
      {
        title: ['', [Validators.required]],
        stageId: [-1, [ValidateSelect]],
        subjectId: [-1, [ValidateSelect]],
        levelId: [-1, [ValidateSelect]],
        teacherAccount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        isActive: ['', [Validators.required],],
        date: ['', [Validators.required]],
        startTime: ['', [Validators.required]],
        endTime: ['', [Validators.required]],
        otherTeacherEmail:[]
      }
      ,{
        validator: this.validate('startTime', 'endTime'),
      }
    );
```

where validator is the custom validator, here is its code

```
validate(
    startTime: string,
    endTime: string
  ) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const start = formGroup.controls[startTime];
      const end = formGroup.controls[endTime];

      if (start.value > end.value) {
        end.setErrors({invalid:true})
      } 
      else {
        end.setErrors(null);
      }
    };
  }
```

in my html page I added  2 spans to appear if each validator fails, but the span of the custom validator is the only one that appears, here is the code

```
<div>
                  <input class="form-control" [ngxTimepicker]="end" formControlName="endTime" readonly>
                  <ngx-material-timepicker #end></ngx-material-timepicker>
             </div>
     
                <span
                class="errorVal"
                *ngIf="formSubmitted && form.controls['endTime'].hasError('required')"
              >
                required
              </span>
                <span
              class="errorVal"
              *ngIf="formSubmitted && form.controls['endTime'].hasError('invalid')"              
              >
              invalid time
              </span>
```

Comment: because you clear out any other errors , remove  
        end.setErrors(nulll);

Comment: The validate method should return null when there are no errors, and some other object when there are errors, so instead of `end.setErrors`, you should directly return. I recommend to start off with [some example](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators).

Comment: In general is a "bad idea" use setErrors. If your function `validate` return null if valid and an object if not valid, rememebr taht you need ask about `form.errors` (you're validating the formGroup, not the formControl. NOTE: if you want to validate only the formControl, you can use some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939157/angular-conditional-required-validator-between-two-fields/65939591#65939591)